# Consuming file sent via PUT method in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, put

I am integrating with a 3rd party API (echosign) and one of the things I need to specify is a callbackURL.

"A publicly accessible url to which EchoSign will do a HTTP PUT operation with the final signed PDF. HTTP authentication is supported using standard embedded syntax - i.e. http://username:password@your.server.com/path/to/file. EchoSign can also ping your system using HTTP GET every time there is a new agreement event. Please contact support@echosign.com if you wish to use this option."

How would this work in rails?

I was going to expose a controller method. Would this need to be PUT method?
How would I access the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to provide a put route to an action that will consume the upload.

Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#what-gets-uploaded for the upload action

Enter s.th. like the following to your config/routes.rb to add a PUT Route to the eccording controller..

```
match '/mycallbackurl' => 'MyEchoController#upload', :via => :put
```